# Wearing shorts with hairy legs in Moscow

Tags: russia, clothing, etiquette, moscow

Is it appropriate to wear shorts or walk around beaches if you have hairy legs, as a man in Moscow?

Comment: I HIGHLY doubt that's a problem.

Comment: I would expect the outside temperature answers that questions...

Comment: @Aganju: Depends on exactly how furry those legs are.

Comment: It is a modern (maybe even an American) thing to shave legs, till recently nobody bothered about hairy legs. As a man you can get away with bein hairy all over.

Comment: "Is it ok to have two arms and two eyes and walk in Moscow".. no different than this question. You are overthinking it buddy.. unless we are having a gorilla level hairy legs.. that's a different story.

Comment: The hairier your legs and body, the better. It allows sweat to evaporate at a faster rate, allowing you to exercise a lot harder in the heat without overheating. Without hair, the wheat will have to evaporate directly off your skin, but there is limited room for sweat there, any excess sweat will drop on the ground and won't provide you with the necessary cooling. With more hair the sweat will form small droplets on the hair fibers, the total amount of sweat that is evaporating can then be much larger. An additional benefit is that the hair makes it more difficult for mosquitoes to sting you.

Comment: @CountIblis If you've got enough hair that you can cultivate wheat, perhaps it's about time you covered up :)

Comment: Curiously you're the second person to ask specifically about shorts in Russia, after [Is wearing shorts in Transsiberian trains okay](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74588). Not sure when Russia got this reputation for strict [sartorial excellence](https://www.google.com.sl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F9velZwI3Cyk%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9velZwI3Cyk&docid=QXFzav1zzGwCBM&tbnid=LDMFdOe32S0W3M%3A&w=1280&h=720&bih=713&biw=1462&ved=0ahUKEwjgwIeusYzPAhXDtRQKHXQEB1cQMwgrKA8wDw&iact=mrc&uact=8)...

Comment: @user568458 probably from [this fine documentary about a former Soviet country](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borat)

Comment: @Willeke I don't know anyone, apart from people sport cyclists, who shaves their legs. I would find it weirder to see a guy with shaven legs than a guy with hairy legs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @HeidelBerGensis have said: "Unless you have gorilla level hairy legs" noone really cares.

But if there is still a question you can watch a few videos, like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDRuP3NyuTA

You can see a few guys wearing shorts.

Comment: Lol, like you can concentrate on guys` legs in this video!

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Well I couldn't find any video that would show only guys with hairy legs in shorts.

Comment: As a Moscow habitant I can say even more: nobody cares of your legs, you can do whatever you want, seriously :) 
It is not recommended to walk around without a t-shirt or so, but shorts, especially in summer, are a common thing

Comment: Some guys have long hair and stylish clothes, and shorts, so if you look from behind, only the hairy legs give a clue of their gender. :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd strengthen the point by Karlson and the comment by Willeke:

Not only does noone care if you have hairy legs, but in Russia, as a guy, you'd probably be getting odd looks and your sexuality would be questioned if you would be found to have *shaved* legs.

Comment: @pnuts In the pedantic sense you are right, but I believe a Q needs to be A'd as generally as possible. What if the OP decides to "be on the safe side" and thinks "my legs are gorilla-like, I'll better shave them"?

Comment: This is the point exactly. Hairy legs are considered manly in Russia to the best of my knowledge, and men in Russia are expected to behave in a manly way, because everything else is ‘gay’[citation needed].