# Is wearing shorts in Transsiberian trains okay

Tags: china, russia, clothing, etiquette, mongolia

I am planning a trip with the Transsiberian railway in September. I read that they heat the train compartments very well. Since I am more the low temperature loving guy, I'd like to wear shorts when the temperature is rather high (+20°C) and don't want to carry too much clothes on the trip. Is it okay to wear shorts in the train (my favorite one is light green and very noticeable)? I am not vain but may be this is somehow inappropriate. Or will I just be the дурак (idiot) then like my father was 20 years ago on Ibiza with his knee high socks, sandals his "I am the Boss" basecap? 
[image]

Comment: Not sure where we get this self-consciousness from: http://waytorussia.net/TransSiberian/Life.html

Comment: Related maybe: [Wearing shorts with hairy legs in Moscow](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74450/32134)

Comment: @Karlson Great link, thank you! The survival guide looks also very useful.

Comment: Let me give you a little traveltip courtecy of Larry David: https://youtu.be/uBlRmAAp6J8

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's absolutely OK. Moreover, Russians' concept of appropriate clothing in trains is very very very relaxed; many people will wear clothing that they will never wear in many other public places (such as old worn shirt or tracksuit-like trousers, etc.) Of course, this depends on the class, in the platzkart (3rd class) passengers have most relaxed clothing, while the passengers of the expensive classes tend to wear more formal clothing, although even they will often change to something relaxed when in train. I can only suggest you not wearing too 'toxic'-colored clothing (or 'neon'-colored, very bright and flashy); but the one on photo seems ok for me.

However, not every train and not every carriage will be heated too much, especially in September. This depends on train type, carriage type and conductor, so I will not rely on having only shorts with me. The weather in September can also be unpredictable. Also, newer carriages have air conditioning, so they do not become hot. Check the AC availability when booking (though this may be non-obvious).

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with a toxic green color?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337, I just imagine a person wearing all toxic clothing. People will really notice him on the train and probably it will look weird. One explanation that I can think of is that people wear relaxed clothing, not most fashioned one, and very bright toxic colors look as if the person wanted to be the most fashioned on the train. However, this may be just my personal attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "toxic" colours? Do you mean like what might be called neon colours ([image search example](https://www.google.com.sl/search?q=neon+clothes&espv=2&biw=1462&bih=713&tbm=isch&tbo=u), [QE2 example](https://twitter.com/imteddybless/status/741682424539648000))?

Comment: I believe @Petr is describing flamboyant, bright, and/or flashy clothing and colors, which would attract attention (possibly unwanted).

Comment: @user568458 exactly. We just call them poisonous or toxic, or radioactive here.

Comment: So true... Nobody cares what you wear in the train. This is what makes some like me dislike trains. I personally get tired riding more than 1 night, having to watch these wife-beater shirts, bellies and smell ramyeon.

Comment: @culebrón, yes, the smell is the worst!

Comment: @user568458, SnakeDoc, exactly.

Comment: @Petr I was just asking because 'neon' colors are high on trend at the moment.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337, probably that's exactly the reason why I feel that they would look strange on the train. Usually, one does not wear trendy clothing in trains.

Answer (score 12):

I did a tour on the Transsiberian last year in early September. I was in shorts for most of the time (including the long station breaks). Nobody gave a damn. (I should add that it was entirely in Russia, no streches in Mongolia or China; it may be different there.)

On the other hand, visiting Jordan I was stared at *a lot* for being a guy, having long hair and wearing shorts, even though nobody said anything (I just clearly stood out as a tourist). So going by this difference, there should be no problem at all in Russia.

I’ll also echo what Petr has said about the dress code on train being much more relaxed than that outside of the train.